# Identificar tipo de variable que el usuario ingrese mediante Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tipos

Buen día tengo un error al Identificar el tipo de una variable con el prompt.
Al parecer el prompt convierte el dato que ingresemos a el tipo de dato String, ya que al hacer un console.log(typeof(*)) ala variable para ve el tipo de dato asi ponga un numero o texto este me lanza como una String.
Quisiera saber como podria identificar el tipo de variable que se registre en el prompt. 
OJO identificar no convertir a String o Number.
Lo que quiero lograr esque al poner texto la variable sea de tipo String y al poner un numero sea de tipo Number.
Aqui les dejo el codigo simnplificado y facil de entender.

```js
var indentificador = prompt("Introduzca un numero o letra");

console.log(typeof(indentificador));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    

    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: De hecho, lo que escribes en prompt es texto, una cadena de caracteres. No es que javascript lo convierta, simplemente todo lo que ingreses serán carácteres.

Comment: Si deseas usar eso para por ejemplo luego parsear el valor de prompt a un numero, no es necesario entonces usar typeof, de hecho usarlo sería un error, puesto que prompt te va a dar siempre el valor como cadena de texto, en su lugar si lo que quieres es usar eso para convertir lo que haya en prompt a un numero, puedes mejor verificar si el resultado de hacer parseFloat o parseInt al valor de prompt sea diferente de NaN.

Comment: En caso de que no desees este comportamiento (para pasar de un string a numero), entonces simplemente no tendría sentido preguntar typeof del prompt, por que primero: typeof solo obtiene el tipo de un solo valor (no de varios) y segundo, lo que siempre se obtiene desde prompt es una cadena de texto.

Comment: Creo que no entediste jejej perdon por no explicarlo perfectamente, yo use el TypeOff para identificar que tipo de dato recogia y es ahi donde me di cuenta que todo lo que se introduce en el prompt es String.

Comment: En todo caso lo que quiero es identificar el tipo de dato que introduce un usuario. Intente usar prompt pero no resulta ya que lo convierte a String.

Comment: Hay otro metodo para poder identificar el tipo d dato que ingrese el usuario.?

Comment: Darle al usuario la capacidad de escoger el tipo de dato antes de definir el dato. Puedes hacerlo mediante <select> en HTML e incluir varios tipos. Me parece la opción más sencilla

Comment: Porfavor lee mas detenidamente nuestros comentarios (el de Mateo y el mio), sobre todo el de Mateo, eso dará sentido a la respuesta.

Comment: No, no hay forma de 'decirle' a un prompt que use los datos pasados como un tipo u otro, porque siempre lo pasado será un string, sin embargo una opción que puedes tener es hacer un split de aquello obtenido en el prompt, recorrer cada valor e intentar hacer diferentes procesos para poder mirar que tipo de dato es (no uses typeof directamente, primero debes intentar convertirlo a algún y luego usar typeof en ese valor convertido, de lo contrario siempre te va a devolver string)...

Comment: Por cierto, a estas alturas es conveniente que reformules tu pregunta, solo editala. Porque la gente no tardará en darle puntos negativos

Comment: Lo que necesito especificamente es detectar el valor que el usuario ingrese y de acuerdo a eso ejecutar una serie de instrucciones, por ejemplo si introduce texto ejecutar instruccion a y si es numero ejecutar instruccion b. Darle al usuario a escoger no es lo que necesito. Lo que quiero es identificar el tipo de dato que introduzca el usuario.

Comment: Lo introducido en un prompt siempre será texto y esto no hay forma de cambiarlo, tambien, no hay forma directa de detectar si aquello que escribiste en un prompt es texto o numeros o lo que sea, porque aquello escrito en un prompt, así le hayas puesto letras numeros o cualquier cosa (lo que sea), siempre al final será una cadena de texto, ahora, si quieres una manera indirecta si que hay una posibilidad.

Comment: Y cual seria esa posibilidad.?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`prompt()` **siempre devuelve un string**, usa `isNan()`  (Not A Number).

```js
var indentificador = prompt("Introduzca un numero o letra");

if (isNaN(indentificador)) {
  console.log("String");
} else {
  console.log("Numero");
}
```

Comment: Excelente gracias por el apoyo voy comenzando y no sabia que se podia usar el isNaN de esa forma gracias.

Comment: Aunque lo que escribiste por si no identifica ya me diste la idea

Comment: Lo he editado, ahora si?

Comment: si introduzco true me lo detecta como string lo cual claramente esta mal

Comment: Segun el enunciado "Lo que quiero lograr esque al poner texto la variable sea de tipo String y al poner un numero sea de tipo Number.", no habla de booleanos

Comment: Exacto según el enunciado que di resuelve el problema, En si la idea esta bien de poner el isNaN porque al poner texto este lanza tipo de dato NaN lo cual hace ejecutar la condicion y si es numero  ejecuta el otro. Pero yo cambie el console.log que pusiste porque yo no quiero ejcutar eso jejej, Pero resolvio mi duda aunque sigue sin cambiar el tipo de variable. Por que en el "else" falta poner parseInt(Identificador) asi cambia el tipo de variable a entero si es un numero solo eso eraaa..

Comment: Pero gracias por tu ayuda no sabia eso del isNaN, como digo voy recién iniciando y estoy aprendiendo ya me diste la idea. Thank you

Comment: Recuerda que si ingresas `54sa5da` podría detectarlo como entero ya que retorna  `54` solamente con el `isNan()` se arregla.

Comment: @HERRERA retorna 54 porque es lo primero que encuentra parseFloat o parseInt, lo demas lo descarta, pero si lo primero que encuentra no es un numero, automaticamente eso siempre te devolvera NaN.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let indentificador = prompt("Introduzca un numero o letra");

let parts = indentificador.split(" ");
let parsedVals;

function parseToVal(parts){

  return parts.map(part =>{
    
    if(part == "true" || part == "false") return part == "true"
    if(part == "undefined") return undefined
    if(
      !Number.isNaN(parseFloat(part)) && 
      parseFloat(part).toString().length === part.length
    ){
      return parseFloat(part);
    }else{
      return part;
    }
    if(part == "Infinity" || part == "-Infinity") return part == "Infinity" ? Infinity : -Infinity;
    if(part == "null") return null;
    if(part == "NaN") return NaN;
    
    return part;
    
  });

}

parsedVals = parseToVal(parts);

parsedVals.forEach((elm, i) =>{
  console.log(`${parts[i]} has the type: ${typeof elm}`);
});
```

Esta es una forma de indentificar cualquier tipo de cosa que haya dentro de un string, siempre y cuando tenga el formato adecuado.

Puedes probarlo poniendo por ejemplo:

```
Hola true Infinity NaN 3.14 undefined
```

En el snippet.

Comment: O puedes usar eval() como solución genérica. Te ahorras ifs y conversiones.

Comment: No sabia que eval hacia eso, gracias por la recomendación, dejare esta forma por aquí, aunque es buena idea si lo deseas que pongas la forma con eval, creo que esta muy bien tener varias formas de llegar a un mismo camino.